# How to handle logging in a multiThread java application?

Tags: multithreading, logging, google-compute-engine, disruptor-pattern, google-cloud-stackdriver

I Have a `Multi-threaded java` application running in `google compute engine` instance, this application might reach up to 10k threads, each one doing a task might reach 30 min execution time.

Everything goes well except only on problem, I need to log some info in the tasks that those 5k threads are running, so whenever I put some logs in these tasks even 1 log, it kills the performance cause many threads trying to log concurrently - considered to be an IO operation - so most of them will be BLOCKED most of the time

I've started googling that and I found some solutions:

1- `log4j` with its `AsynchronousLogger` feature using the `disruptor` and `RandomAccessFile`, and its amazing and super fast (all CPU cores are 97% busy) but it writes logs into file - which might reach 100Gb easily - so I don't recommend this.
(I hope I can find a way to make log4j write to `Google StackDriver` directly with same performance)

2- I've tried using `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, so all threads will push logs to this Queue and there are Thread(s) polling logs from this queue and post them to `google StackDriver`. the performance is reduced down to 1/10 of log4j performance.

3- I've read about `Disruptor` and I've started using it, and the performance was really horrible, the worst result and most of threads are just waiting looking for a free slot, I'll share with you my code may be I did something wrong:

```
public class CloudLogger {

        private  static Disruptor<LogEntryEvent> disruptor;
        private static RingBuffer<LogEntryEvent> ringBuffer;
        private static final int RING_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;    

    static {
        disruptor = new Disruptor<LogEntryEvent>(LogEntryEvent.FACTORY , RING_BUFFER_SIZE, new ThreadFactoryLogImpl(), ProducerType.MULTI, new SleepingWaitStrategy());
        disruptor.handleEventsWith(new LogEntryHandler());
        disruptor.start();
        ringBuffer = disruptor.getRingBuffer();
        }

    private static void log(LogEntry logEntry) {
         long sequence = ringBuffer.next();
           final LogEntryEvent _logEntry = ringBuffer.get(sequence);
            _logEntry.setLogEntry(logEntry);
            ringBuffer.publish(sequence);
        }
}
```

LogEntryEvent.class

```
 public class LogEntryEvent 
        {

             public LogEntryEvent() {
                    // do nothing
            }

            LogEntry logEntry;

            public static final EventFactory<LogEntryEvent> FACTORY = new EventFactory<LogEntryEvent>()
            {
                public LogEntryEvent newInstance()
                {
                    return new LogEntryEvent();
                }
            };

            public LogEntry getLogEntry() {
                return logEntry;
            }

            public void setLogEntry(LogEntry logEntry) {
                this.logEntry = logEntry;
            }

        }
```

ThreadFActoryLogImpl.class

```
public class ThreadFactoryLogImpl implements ThreadFactory {

            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                Thread t = new Thread(r);
                t.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
                t.setName("Writting logs thread");
                return t;
            }
        }
```

LogEntryHandler.class

```
public class LogEntryHandler implements EventHandler<LogEntryEvent>
      {
          public void onEvent(final LogEntryEvent logEntry, final long sequence, final boolean endOfBatch) throws Exception
          {
            // I should post here to cloud StackDriver, but Im just testing the performance without it  
              System.out.println(" got sequance is " + sequence + " end of natch " + endOfBatch);
          }

      }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the question here exactly?

If you are asking - which do people prefer, me personally, I would stick with log4j + async logger. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Hi @jasonk, as you can see Im trying to handle a lot of logs in a multi threading app, any thing not clear ? I wanna know whats the best practice in such situation if you know something plz share

Comment: @jasonk ofc I agree, but how to make log4j to send to google cloud StackDrive ?

Comment: @jasonk so don't you think Disruptor can help me on this? can I improve my code to fit my needs better? since log4j cant send logs to `google cloud StackDriver`?